# How to handle std::cin ios::failure?

Tags: c++, exception, cin

I tried to use std::cin exceptions on wrong type input:

```
std::cin.exceptions(ios::failbit);
```

then I tried to handle these exceptions:

```
int a;
try { std::cin >> a; }
catch(ios::failure& f) { std::cout << f.what(); a = 42; }
// I would like to continue the program here
```

However, the failure calls terminate, so the program stops. I know I could just leave the `std::cin.exceptions` off and throw and catch my own exception on failbit, I just wonder if it is possible to avoid the terminate here and if not, when and how should be this `ios::failure` useful on `std::cin`.

Comment: Which standard library implementation are you using?

Comment: @Rakete1111 it is mingw32 6.3.0